# MS Excel - Combining two columns in two sheets by getting all rows of second column for each entry of first colmn

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel workbooks with a sheet each. Each sheet has a single column of unique codes. The first one has around 1000 rows like

```
COLUMN 1
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
1000
```

and the second one is like

```
COLUMN 2
a
b
c
d
.
.
.
r
```

I want to get them both in a single sheet like

```
COLUMN 1          COLUMN 2
1                 a
1                 b
1                 c
1                 d
1                 e
1                 f
1                 g
1                 h
1                 i
1                 j
1                 k
1                 l
1                 m
1                 n
1                 o
1                 p
1                 q
1                 r
2                 a
2                 b
2                 c
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
1000              p
1000              q
1000              r
```

Please suggest how do I do this ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: What you are looking for is called `cross-join` two tables (in SQL terminology). The following two links provide very detailed solutions. (1) Solution using MS Query:  http://www.contextures.com/excelmsquerycartesian.html  (2) Solution with VBA: http://superuser.com/questions/106156/how-can-i-create-a-cross-join-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

With formulas:

In A1 on Sheet3:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A))+1)
```

In B2 on Sheet3:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A))+1)
```

Then copy down.

[image]